# ImportError: No module named flask_wtf

Tags: python, flask, debian, wtforms

for my program I have to use `wtf_forms`. On my computer I have no problem, but with my server it doesn’t work. I have installed (with `apt-get`) `python-flaskext.wtf` and `python-wtforms`, but it seems it’s not enough, and my researchs are clueless. Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Are you using apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does:

```
import flask.ext.wtf
```

seem to resolve your issue?  This works fine for me on raspbian.